# TextInputLayout not showing hint text fully

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-textinputlayout

I'm using recently released Android Design Support Library to show floating label with `EditTexts`. But I'm facing the problem that the Hint text is max hint text does not show fully it show ..... on rest of words.

My Layout is as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_question"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/et_font_size"
        android:theme="@style/MYAppTheme"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Currently showing like this.

[image: Currently showing like this]

Comment: can u add hint parametrically bcs i can not see `android:hint=""` in to your layout

Comment: Reduce the TextSize. The EditText Cant Hold too Long Text in it.

Comment: Yes, i added it programmatically, Click (Currently showing like this) and see the  image too.

Comment: yup i have seen it @Dai

Comment: Your hint is to long for one line and TextInputLayout uses CollapsingTextLayout which measures the hint as a CharSequence.
CharSequence has no notion of a line, thus you can't add more.

It's not quite a hint if it's so long. If you still want to display it consider adding a separate TextView below/above/over and animating it (if want/need to).

Comment: it means no Inbuilted method or something that we can used and solve it.@Rainmaker

Comment: @Dai you can apply marquee effect to scroll out hint

Comment: increase the `android:minLines="2" android:lines="3"`. It's obvious that its exceeding the width

Comment: nop not working @HemanthSTobi

Comment: your hint is too long. Inorder to display hint set minimum lines to 2.

Comment: @Dai it is not possible to add MultiLine hint in TextInputLayout

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using recently released Android Design Support Library to show floating label with EditTexts. But I'm facing the problem that the Hint text is max hint text does not show fully it show

**`AFAIK`** it is not possible to add **MultiLine** hint in `TextInputLayout`

Comment: It should be a comment. this is not an answer